# Scraping with Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for some help with scraping with selenium in python. You need a paid account to view this page so creating a reproducible won't be possible.

[image: The page I'm trying to scrape]

I'm attempting to scrape the data from the blue spots and black arrows.
The data is in this piece of HTML.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 105 68" class="video-summaries__field-arrows" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
      <marker fill="#000" id="default_arrow" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="4" orient="auto" refX="5" refY="2" stroke="none">
         <polygon points="0 0, 5 2, 0 4"></polygon>
      </marker>
      <marker fill="#0033ff" id="hover_arrow" markerWidth="2.9" markerHeight="2.4" orient="auto" refX="2.5" refY="1.2" stroke="none">
         <polygon points="0 0, 2.9 1.2, 0 2.4"></polygon>
      </marker>
   </defs>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M52.5 35.1 37.6 33.3" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_0)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_0" x1="52.5" x2="37.6" y1="35.1" y2="33.3">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M38.2 34.7 76.6 62" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_1)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_1" x1="38.2" x2="76.6" y1="34.7" y2="62">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M61.6 67.8 36.3 63.9" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_2)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_2" x1="61.6" x2="36.3" y1="67.8" y2="63.9">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M36.3 63.9 36.5 26.700000000000003" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_3)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_3" x1="36.3" x2="36.5" y1="63.9" y2="26.700000000000003">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
```

I'm specifically trying to scrape the
`x1`, `x2`,`y1`,`y2`
data from the `linearGradient` tags.

I get the page source by running.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Desktop\webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://football.instatscout.com/teams/9487/video')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_name('pass').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "hRAqIl", " " ))]').click() 
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dropdown-btn:nth-child(12) .video-summaries__checkbox_red ').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dropdown-btn:nth-child(12) > .video-summaries__checkbox').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ixmoFk", " " ))]').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "video-summaries__checkbox-column-inner", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "video-summaries__checkbox-column-row", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 10) and parent::*)]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "video-summaries__checkbox", " " ))]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "dropdown-btn", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 12) and parent::*)]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "video-summaries__checkbox_red", " " ))]').click()
html = driver.page_source
```

in selenium - but I don't know where to go from there.

Ultimately I'd like to scrape it to a data frame, with 'Name' 'X1' 'Y1' 'X2' 'Y2' columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape data using this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html="""
<svg viewBox="0 0 105 68" class="video-summaries__field-arrows" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
      <marker fill="#000" id="default_arrow" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="4" orient="auto" refX="5" refY="2" stroke="none">
         <polygon points="0 0, 5 2, 0 4"></polygon>
      </marker>
      <marker fill="#0033ff" id="hover_arrow" markerWidth="2.9" markerHeight="2.4" orient="auto" refX="2.5" refY="1.2" stroke="none">
         <polygon points="0 0, 2.9 1.2, 0 2.4"></polygon>
      </marker>
   </defs>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M52.5 35.1 37.6 33.3" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_0)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_0" x1="52.5" x2="37.6" y1="35.1" y2="33.3">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M38.2 34.7 76.6 62" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_1)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_1" x1="38.2" x2="76.6" y1="34.7" y2="62">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M61.6 67.8 36.3 63.9" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_2)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_2" x1="61.6" x2="36.3" y1="67.8" y2="63.9">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   <path class="videosummaries-arrows" d="M36.3 63.9 36.5 26.700000000000003" fill="none" marker-end="url(#default_arrow)" stroke="url(#gradient_3)" style="stroke-width: 0.25;"></path>
   <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient_3" x1="36.3" x2="36.5" y1="63.9" y2="26.700000000000003">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
   </svg>
"""

soup=bs(html,"xml")
for lg in soup.find_all("linearGradient",attrs={"gradientUnits":"userSpaceOnUse"}):
    print(lg["x1"],lg["y1"],lg["x2"],lg["y2"])

"""
52.5 35.1 37.6 33.3
38.2 34.7 76.6 62
61.6 67.8 36.3 63.9
36.3 63.9 36.5 26.700000000000003
"""
```

We are using `xml` parser to scrape data from `svg`. I have tested with other + `lxml` parser too. But didn't succeed. Other things is basic, finding element using `tag name` and attribute `gradientUnits`. And finding attribute from `element`.

Comment: I've deleted the replies here to stop any confusion. Thanks for your answer. It's helped me a lot.